Getting the instance of an HTML PrimeVue Datatable
I am kind of new to DataTables.
I have a Primevue/DataTable that instantiates in HTML:
              <DataTable id="cr-list" :value="userCalibrationJobsListData" sortField="calibration_run_id" :sortOrder="-1" scrollable scroll-height="400px"
            table-style="min-width: 50rem" v-model:selection="selectedCalibrationRun" selectionMode="single"
            contextMenu v-model:contextMenuSelection="selectedCalibrationRun" @rowContextmenu="onRowContextMenu"
            :rowStyle="rowStyle">
            <Column field="calibration_run_id" header="Run ID" sortable></Column>
            <Column field="formulation_name" header="Formulation Name" sortable></Column>
            <Column field="gage_id" header="Headwater Basin Gage" sortable></Column>
            <Column field="run_date" header="Run Date" sortable></Column>
            <Column header="Calibration Period" sortable>
              <template #body="slotProps">
                {{ slotProps.data.calibration_start_period }} <span v-if="slotProps.data.calibration_end_period">to</span> {{ slotProps.data.calibration_end_period }}
              </template>
            </Column>
            <Column field="status" header="Status" sortable></Column>
          </DataTable>

I would like to get the instance of a particular DataTable that was created like this, instead of being created with a table ID programmatically.

So, the datatables tag that you're using is specific to jQuery DataTables. I don't think what you're showing us is the same thing. I can't locate any references to <DataTable> as a valid usage of jQuery DataTables in the documentation.

Tbh, I have no idea what the paragraph about DataTable in JS vs HTML instantiation means.  Where does <DataTable> component come from?  A library? Which one? Maybe knowing that would reveal what you mean. Regardless, how the component is created should be inconsequential.  The event listener @init="someFunction", will call someFunction() as a response to DataTable emitting the init event. This is just normal Vue event handling.

And by datatables tag, I mean the tag you used on your question -- it's specific to jQuery DataTables. I suspect you're confusing <DataTable> with jQuery DataTables. The two are not the same.

Our app does not use jQuery.
Datatables is a common library:  https://datatables.net/.

The code shown above is PrimeVue, not DataTables. Suggestion: I would remove the datatables tag from the question, and replace it with the primevue tag. Maybe reword the question slightly, also, so it does not refer to DataTables.

Changed the question to be more specific to PrimeVue
